# How to parse JSON with Jackson2 when Object-Key is random?

Tags: java, json, jackson2

I want to parse a JSON in Java with Jackson2 which has the the following structure:

```
{
 "attachment": {
  "_2K26Z-mLJmMSRnssLwD0zQ": {
    "ext": "jpg",
    "height": 3024,
    "md5": "219c226e0070b7367f90e2f1bff1dfc2",
    "name": "IMG_1871.jpg",
    "ref": "MTUyMTAzNDY5MDUzNElNR18xODcxLmpwZw==",
    "rotate": true,
    "size": 1514957,
    "thumb": "thumb_1024_219c226e0070b7367f90e2f1bff1dfc2",
    "thumb_size": 73119,
    "type": "image",
    "width": 4032
    },
    "_Q7l14s87UquHcAYoolNCuw": {
      "ext": "png",
      "height": 186,
      "md5": "75023fd60d59907376943bf109858336",
      "name": "ns_attach_image_26071520280535225.png",
      "ref": "MTUyMDI4MDUzNTIzMG5zX2F0dGFjaF9pbWFnZV8yNjA3MTUyMDI4MDUzNTIyNS5wbmc=",
      "rotate": true,
      "size": 15182,
      "type": "image",
      "width": 347
    }
  },
  "title": "Test Title"
}
```

My problem is that I do not know how to handle the key of the attachments, because I can not define a class with the field with unknown name.

What works is

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Note note = mapper.readValue(fileio, Note.class);
```

where the class Note is

```
public class Note {
   private String title;
   private Object attachment;

   public String getTitle() {
      return title;
   }

   public void setTitle(String title) {
      this.title = title;
   }

   public Object getAttachment() {
      return attachment;
   }

   public void setAttachment(Object attachment) {
      this.attachment = attachment;
   }
}
```

But I'd like to use an class with Name Attachment which holds all the fields in the json with the key "_2K26Z-mLJmMSRnssLwD0zQ".

Comment: Would [@JsonAnySetter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnySetter.html) work for you? It lets you store unknown keys in a map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Map`, so that a key of an attachment would be a key in the map, and value in the map would be an object representing fields of the attachment. Like this:

```
public class Attachment {
    private String ext;
    private int height;
    private String md5;
    private String name;
    private String ref;
    private boolean rotate;
    private int size;
    private String thumb;
    private int thumb_size;
    private String type;
    private int width;

}

public class Note {
    private String title;

    private Map<String, Attachment> attachment = new HashMap<>();
}
```